# ChessBase 15 Alternative Annotation Language

Tags: chessbase

I am still investigating potential causes of the problem I have spotted at

[Comments from (commented !) games lost in "ChessBase to Scid on the go" conversion process](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/29250/comments-from-commented-games-lost-in-chessbase-to-scid-on-the-go-conversi)

So, in ChessBase 15, in "File --> Options --> Languages" the alternative annotation language is set as follows by default to "Deutsch" :

[image]

If I change it to English, click apply, close ChessBase 15 an reopen it, by some kind of supranatural miracle of nature, the alternative annotation language is again equal to Deutsch. Bonus : even if I only close the options windows and reopen it, I will "Deutsch" again for the alternative annotation language. Isn't it beautiful ?

As I am still not desperate about this software, would someone have an idea ?